# How to do continuous integration with Hudson for Maven 3 multi-module projects well?

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, hudson

It is my current impression that is impossible to do CI for a Maven 3 multi-module project **well** using Hudson (or Jenkins).

The situation seems to be that you have 2 realistic options of building a multi-module Maven 3 project with Hudson:

1. A freestyle project can also Build Maven projects, and with the incremental/recursive option it apparently should be able to deal with building only the necessary subtrees of the complete project tree.
2. A legacy, severly deprecated, with lots of warnings, Maven2/3 legacy build.

With the first option there is the significant disadvantage that your complete project looks like one big blob in Hudson, there is no visibility on the individual subprojects and there is no option for building individual subprojects and their dependees.

With the second option you have to basically swallow very little faith inducing warnings about legacy and "do not use" in order to find out that yes, it will build your multi-module project but the functionality of triggering subproject builds is completely broken and there is no intention of fixing this.

The only alternative I can figure out is to revert to Maven 2 for the build on the server, in which case the legacy plugin seems to work and even the individual sub-project builds can be triggered. But then I'm stuck on Maven 2.

I find my requirements to be rather conservative but I am completely stymied by the lack of Maven support in Hudson/Jenkins. Here's what I would expect:

- ability to recognize multi-module projects and build them using Maven 3
- ability to have "incremental" builds of such a multi-module project (i.e. only changed modules and its dependees)
- ability to see the current status of the multi-module project and what sub-module has failed/succeeded/is unstable

The Maven project in question consists of about 84 Maven modules in a multi-module configuration with a common parent and a split into different subsystems. We are using Hudson 3.1.0.

Do I have any chance of achieving this?

Comment: What version of Jenkins/Hudson are you running?

Comment: We're using Hudson 3.1.0, added it to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is impossible to do it *well* with the current Maven 2/3 project type.

I have done it *well enough* using a matrix / multi-configuration project type, and adding a "Module" axis manually.  The configuration of the matrix job is a pain, and you have to remember to update your axis any time you add, remove or rename a module.  But once configuration is complete, this solution works well for building.  You can see the build and test results for each module separately, or integrated under the matrix job.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my sanity. :) Doing the manual configuration of the modules is what I was hoping to prevent. Do you know of any tools to generate the relevant config?

Comment: No.  I also don't know of anyone else who has done this, so there might not be such a tool.  You might be able create a job that builds or updates the matrix job for you, and a quick look at the [API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/matrix/package-summary.html) suggests this is possible, but I've never tried it.  I've just found the [DynamicAxis plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/DynamicAxis+Plugin); combining that with the [parameterized trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague has been working on implementing Maven 3 multi-module functionality in Jenkins.

https://github.com/adamcin/maven-plugin

Not sure what the upstream acceptance status is.